# validate an image before uploading in php

Tags: php

i am uploadind an image in php using copy function. my imade doesnt display when the image height is less than 981pz & width is less than 477pz

Comment: Wow you should first read your message over before posting? It does not make complete sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

image size validator usually place in php code/server side.

after user upload the file you can check the size of image using

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path)

if ($width > x )
    do something

if ($height > x)
    do something
```

if you want to check file type and also image resolution uploaded by user, can use

```
$info = getimagesize("my-great-photo.jpg");

and the result is:
Array
(
    [0] => 300 //width
    [1] => 200 //height
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="300" height="200"
    [bits] => 8 //size
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg //image type
)

$width = $info[0];
$height = $info[1];
$type = $info[mime]
```

[check this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But if you are looking for a way in PHP to find the height and width of an image you can use the [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function.

You can use it as:

```
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($image_file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the copy function is not supported by all hosts, and is considered to be a security risk. If you would like to upload an image to your server, look into creating an HTML form like what has been done [here](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp). If you do this, you will be able to get the mime type from the $_FILES array, and know not only whether or not you are uploading a picture, but also what type of picture you are upload (e.g. png, jpeg, gif).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to restrict uploaded image size, then as others said you can use [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function, but if it is an issue with displaying the image, you can use a script like [timthumb](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/), which you pass image path to, and it will resize it to the dimensions you specify (on fly).